# Cookie header rfc 2965 Version attribute

Tags: http, cookies

I'm reading rfc2965 for Cookie header. The syntax for a cookie header is:

```
cookie          =  "Cookie:" cookie-version 1*((";" | ",") cookie-value)
cookie-value    =  NAME "=" VALUE [";" path] [";" domain] [";" port]
cookie-version  =  "$Version" "=" value
NAME            =  attr
VALUE           =  value
path            =  "$Path" "=" value
domain          =  "$Domain" "=" value
port            =  "$Port" [ "=" <"> value <"> ]
```

So the cookie header should have a single cookie-version. Later in that spec in paragraph 7.2 there is a spoofing example:

```
     Cookie: $Version="1"; session_id="1234",
             $Version="1"; session_id="1111"; $Domain=".cracker.edu"
```

How does having two versions for each cookies relate to the syntax above? In what scenario is it possible? In case proxies fold the multiple cookie headers?

What about scenario where there are multiple Set-Cookie headers each cookie with a different Version attribute?

Comment: Why are you even looking at this document? It's very very obsolete...

Comment: I have a legacy code that I have to patch.

Comment: @JulianReschke is correct, you should really stick to [RFC 6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265).

Comment: I can't, there are applications that are using this spec that would get broken if I would just switch to newer spec and I can't ask them to update as I don't even know who they are.

Comment: What applications do use RFC 2965?

Comment: Proprietary applications.